# How to retrive matching and non-matching records in Mysql?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to retrive matching and non-matching records in mysql.

```
center_wise_test_rates:

lab_id   category_name   test_id   test_name           rate
------   -------------   --------  ---------           ------
2        Cardiology       9        Blood Sug           1200
2        Cardiology      10       Total Cholesterol    1500
2        Cardiology      11       HDL                  1100
2        Cardiology      12       LDL                  750
```

```
test_list

test_id  category_name       test_name
-------  -------------       ---------
9        Cardiology          Blood Sug
10       Cardiology          Total Cholesterol
11       Cardiology          HDL
12       Cardiology          LDL
57       Cardiology          abc
```

From center_wise_test_rates and test_list tables based on category_name and lab_id the matching record will getting but non matching record i.e., **test name** 'abc' is not getting.

My Query:

```
SELECT cwtr.lab_id
      ,cwtr.category_name
      ,cwtr.test_id
      ,cwtr.test_name
      ,cwtr.rate
FROM `center_wise_test_rates` AS cwtr
LEFT OUTER JOIN test_list AS tl ON tl.category_name = (SELECT DISTINCT category_name
                                                       FROM center_wise_test_rates 
                                                       WHERE category_name='Cardiology')
                                AND tl.test_id = cwtr.test_id
WHERE cwtr.lab_id = '2'
AND cwtr.category_name = 'Cardiology'
```

Output:

```
lab_id  category_name  test_id  test_name        rate
------   ------------  -------- ---------        ----
2        Cardiology       9     Blood Sug        1200
2        Cardiology      10    Total Cholesterol 1500
2        Cardiology      11       HDL            1100
2        Cardiology      12       LDL            750
```

Expected Output:

```
 lab_id  category_name  test_id   test_name          rate
 ------  -------------  --------  ---------          ----
  2      Cardiology       9       Blood Sug          1200
  2      Cardiology      10       Total Cholesterol  1500
  2      Cardiology      11       HDL                1100
  2      Cardiology      12       LDL                 750
  2      Cardiology      57       abc                 Null
```

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: It will be better if you share your attempt also.

Comment: I think this pictures taken from his/her teacher currently

Answer (score 0):

The all you need is a LEFT JOIN -

```
SELECT (SELECT lab_id
        FROM center_wise_test_rates
        WHERE category_name = tl.category_name
        LIMIT 1) lab_id
      ,tl.category_name
      ,tl.test_id
      ,tl.test_name
      ,cwtr.rate 
FROM test_list tl
LEFT JOIN center_wise_test_rates cwtr ON tl.test_id = cwtr.test_id
                                      AND tl.category_name = cwtr.category_name
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9c2d672df33f1997689657c2314f0ba3) is the demo.

Comment: Thanks! The code is good, but it did not written my expected output.

Comment: @suresh, Please try now.

Comment: Your query returns my output, but it did not return my Expected output. If, is it possible to return my expected output by changing two tables. If, it is let me know?

Comment: Thank you @ Ankit Bajpai. It's Woking fine.

Comment: @suresh, You are always welcome. Glad to know that I was able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It will select all values from TABLE1 where criteria match or not.

```
 SELECT coulmn1, column2 FROM TABLE1 LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.ID= TABLE2.ID WHERE NAME = 'ABC'
```